# React.js - Autocomplete: How To Hide Suggest Lst While Clicking On Other Areas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I read this [tutorial](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/simple-react-autocomplete-component/) and try to make an auto complete text box.

Here is part of the code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {SearchInput, SearchUL, SearchLI} from './index.style';

// based on this: https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/simple-react-autocomplete-component/
const Autocomplete = ({suggestions = []}) => {
  const [activeSuggestion, setActiveSuggestion] = useState(0);
  const [filteredSuggestions, setFilteredSuggestions] = useState([]);
  const [showSuggestions, setShowSuggestions] = useState(false);
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);

  // timer id
  let typingTimer;
  //
  let doneTypingInterval = 1000;

  // on change
  const onChange = e => {
    // input
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

    // match
    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      suggestion =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );

    // set state
    setActiveSuggestion(0);
    setFilteredSuggestions(filteredSuggestions);
    setShowSuggestions(true);
    setUserInput(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  // onclick
  const onClick = e => {
    // set state
    setActiveSuggestion(0);
    setFilteredSuggestions([]);
    setShowSuggestions(false);
    setUserInput(e.currentTarget.innerText); //?

    console.log('on click');
  };

  // done
  const doneTyping = () => {
    console.log('done type');
    setIsTyping(false);
  };

  // key down
  const onKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      // 1. enter key
      // state
      setActiveSuggestion(0);
      setShowSuggestions(false);
      setUserInput(filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      // 2. up arrow key
      // no active, out
      if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
        return;
      }

      // go up, -1
      setActiveSuggestion(activeSuggestion - 1);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      // 3. down arr
      if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
        return;
      }

      // go down +1
      setActiveSuggestion(activeSuggestion + 1);
    } else {
    }
  };

  // key up
  const onKeyUp = e => {
    // clear old timer
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);

    // has val, then clean up
    if (e.currentTarget.value) {
      setIsTyping(true);
      typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
  };

  // tmp: sugList
  let suggestionsListComponent;
  // state: show and u-input
  if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
    // state: filterSug.len
    if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
      // ul + li
      suggestionsListComponent = (
        <SearchUL>
          {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
            return (
              <SearchLI key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
                {suggestion}
              </SearchLI>
            );
          })}
        </SearchUL>
      );
    } else {
      // no
      suggestionsListComponent = (
        <div>
          <em>No suggestions!</em>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  // --------
  // NOTE: this makes the drop down list disappear, but not able to click the list
  // --------
  const onBlur = () => {
    setShowSuggestions(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SearchInput
        type="text"
        onChange={onChange}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
        value={userInput}
        isTyping={isTyping}
        //onBlur={onBlur}
      />
      {suggestionsListComponent}
    </>
  );
};

export default Autocomplete;
```

Sorry, proxy not allow me to upload image. In summary, when you start typing, if match, there will be a dropdown list. Click on 1 of the item, the search box will be filled with it.

Now image you type half way, then your mouse moves to other areas, so like `onBlur`, the dropdown list is not able to disappear.

I tried to make a `onBlur` function

```
const onBlur = () => {
    setShowSuggestions(false);
  };
```

and have something like this:

```
return (
    <>
      <SearchInput
        type="text"
        onChange={onChange}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
        value={userInput}
        isTyping={isTyping}
        //onBlur={onBlur}
      />
      {suggestionsListComponent}
    </>
  );
```

This time, if I click other areas, the dropdown list is able to hide, but when I do normal typing and select dropdown *item*, the selected item is not able to go to the search box.

Full code [here](https://github.com/kenpeter/test_formik)

Comment: Hey @kenpeter, the answer that I wrote below helpful to you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a sandbox link for you. Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/testformik-xgl3w

In this, I have wrapped your component with `div` and passed a `ref`. And on `componentDidMount` I am listening to click on the `document` and calling the function and if the target clicked is different than the AutoComplete components ( input and suggestion ) I close the suggestion box.

This is the new code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { SearchInput, SearchUL, SearchLI } from "./index.style";

const inputRef = React.createRef();
// based on this: https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/simple-react-autocomplete-component/
const Autocomplete = ({ suggestions = [] }) => {
  const [activeSuggestion, setActiveSuggestion] = useState(0);
  const [filteredSuggestions, setFilteredSuggestions] = useState([]);
  const [showSuggestions, setShowSuggestions] = useState(false);
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);

  const handleOuterClick = e => {
    if (!inputRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setShowSuggestions(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleOuterClick);
  }, []);

  // timer id
  let typingTimer;
  //
  let doneTypingInterval = 1000;

  // on change
  const onChange = e => {
    // input
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

    // match
    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      suggestion =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );

    // set state
    setActiveSuggestion(0);
    setFilteredSuggestions(filteredSuggestions);
    setShowSuggestions(true);
    setUserInput(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  // onclick
  const onClick = e => {
    // set state
    setActiveSuggestion(0);
    setFilteredSuggestions([]);
    setShowSuggestions(false);
    setUserInput(e.currentTarget.innerText); //?

    console.log("on click");
  };

  // done
  const doneTyping = () => {
    console.log("done type");
    setIsTyping(false);
  };

  // key down
  const onKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      // 1. enter key
      // state
      setActiveSuggestion(0);
      setShowSuggestions(false);
      setUserInput(filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      // 2. up arrow key
      // no active, out
      if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
        return;
      }

      // go up, -1
      setActiveSuggestion(activeSuggestion - 1);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      // 3. down arr
      if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
        return;
      }

      // go down +1
      setActiveSuggestion(activeSuggestion + 1);
    } else {
    }
  };

  // key up
  const onKeyUp = e => {
    // clear old timer
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);

    // has val, then clean up
    if (e.currentTarget.value) {
      setIsTyping(true);
      typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
  };

  // tmp: sugList
  let suggestionsListComponent;
  // state: show and u-input
  if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
    // state: filterSug.len
    if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
      // ul + li
      suggestionsListComponent = (
        <SearchUL>
          {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
            return (
              <SearchLI key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
                {suggestion}
              </SearchLI>
            );
          })}
        </SearchUL>
      );
    } else {
      // no
      suggestionsListComponent = (
        <div>
          <em>No suggestions!</em>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div ref={inputRef}>
      <SearchInput
        type="text"
        onChange={onChange}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
        value={userInput}
        isTyping={isTyping}
      />
      {suggestionsListComponent}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Autocomplete;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, just a question, what exact is ref and why do we use here?

Comment: Hey `ref` is the react way of accessing DOM element, we have used it here in order to check if we have clicked AutoComplete elements or not. You can read more about refs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

Update your `onBlur` function using timer, like this:

```
const onBlurr = () => {
   setTimeout(() => setShowSuggestions(false), 500);
};
```